# ajax calls not executing

Tags: ajax, recursion

I am throwing an ajax call that downloads a few images.
At the same time, I need another loop that has to check if all the images have been downloaded (I know how many will be downloaded). I do it this way:

```
function check_download(){
    ajax_call...
    success: function(amount){if(amount < 40) check_download()}
}
```

call download_images(); // this starts the process of downloading images
call check_download();

So I launch the download and I send an ajax call to check if it has downloaded the 40 images. If not, then I want to launch another ajax call to check again, and so on.

But it only throws 2 ajax calls. The second one gets frozen and it does not return any value, so no loop is being done and I cannot check the progress of the download.

Any idea on how to launch several ajax calls to achieve this?

Comment: what makes you think the success handler gets the amount as it's argument? you need to paste more code. also, ajax calls are not "thrown". only exceptions are, though some people throw strings too. i consider that bad style

Comment: @JanusTroelsen I thought throwing a function might be a good style to implement an exception with continuation, isn't it?

Comment: @JanDvorak: it's subjective I guess. i think it lends itself to spaghetti style error handling.

Comment: Well, maybe throwing is not the best way to say it. Just calling a method with an ajax call inside.  The "amount" is correctly calculated because I've written it into javascript console and it has the value it must have.